# ElasticSearch: compare two geopoints in document

Tags: elasticsearch, geopoints

Considering the following document, I want to query only documents that have current location within 1mile of destination location.

```
{
  current_location: {
      lat: 34.0583,
      lon: -118.2476
  },
  destination_location: {
    lat: 33.989521,
    lon: -117.531614
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that geo distance filter:

```
{
   "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "geo_distance": {
                    "distance": "1.6km",
                    "destination_location": "34.05,-118.24"
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

34.05 is the latitude and (-118.24) is the longitude.

1mile = 1.6km